# Прокрутка длинного текста в ToolBar Title

Tags: java, android, textview, toolbar

В vk, например, длинные имя и фамилия прокручиваются по кругу, как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, с помощью рефлексии [можно добраться](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28879135/7129209) и установить соответствующие атрибуты для `TextView`, в котором отображается тайтл в `Toolbar`:

```
TextView titleTextView = null;

try {
    Field f = toolbar.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTitleTextView");
    f.setAccessible(true);
    titleTextView = (TextView) f.get(toolbar);

    titleTextView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    titleTextView.setFocusable(true);
    titleTextView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    titleTextView.requestFocus();
    titleTextView.setSingleLine(true);
    titleTextView.setSelected(true);
    titleTextView.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);

} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    // some actions
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    // some actions
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. А как поменять скорость прокрутки? И уменьшить частоту прокрутки?

Comment: @никитадолгошей, Не могу ответить на Ваши вопросы, но что-то мне подсказывает, что для этого нужно очень-очень глубоко копать, потому как эти атрибуты находятся где-то глубоко в реализации `TextView`, либо в реализации `TextUtils`.

Comment: Ладно, и на этом спасибо)